# Testing Linsched with sample code

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

I recently came across Linsched where one can simulate in user-space some of the kernel scheduler (I believe CFS) functionality. Now following along the progress of the scheduler, a port to 3.3.4 was announced [1] where they claim to have all the simulation code in ~20 lines. So after cloning the repository and following the instructions at [1], I try:

```
~/linsched/tools$ ls
firewire  hv  lguest  nfsd  perf  power  slub  testing  usb  virtio
```

Which is expected as the repository that I cloned contains all the kernel code, but the linsched folder that was supposed to be present in tools/ isn't there. Has anyone else had luck with running linsched with 3.3.4? If so, where can I find more information on it? Thanks!

[1] http://lists.linaro.org/pipermail/linaro-sched-sig/2012-March/000013.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured out what the code was after emailing a few people, I'm posting the answer here for others, after checking out the code, you have to switch to linsched-alpha branch.